# django dropdownlist onchange submission

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, html-select

I am showing to the user a dropdown list from this form:

```
class CronForm(forms.Form):
    days = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Day.objects.all().order_by('day'))

class Day(models.Model):
    day = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    month = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.day
```

And It is shown at the template this way:

```
<form method="post" onchange=change()>
    {{ days }}
</form>
```

What I want is to submit this form when the user selects an option from the dropdown list. For example, the user could be redirected to a new url, and internally the program would capture the POST data. But everything I find is related to the `<select>` tag, like calling a javascript function onchange of the select element. But as the select element is IN the ModelChoiceField form, I don't know how to do it.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

solved following this [link](http://djangosteps.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/filtered-menus-in-django/)

```
days = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Day.objects.all().order_by('alias'), widget=forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'refresh()'}))
```

Comment: and if I only want to filter the objects that are shown? 
I have tried `queryset=Day.objects.get(Q(day="15")).order_by('alias')`,  `queryset=Day.objects.filter(day="15").order_by('alias')` and many other options to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Find the `id` of the dropdown using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com). It should be `id_days` as you are using the name `days`. Then bind jQuery `change` event to it.

```
$(function(){
    $('#id_days').change(function(){
        $('#id_of_form').submit();
    });
});
```